# creating a list in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I want to create a MySQL database with one column containing a list(variable in size for different entries). I also have to allow entries to be added to that list later.
What is the way to do this ?

Comment: describe more about your question

Comment: I want to make a list containing all the friends of one user(for all the users).

Answer (score 0):

The way this is typically done is to create a separate column that groups the items together:

```
list_id, value
1, a
1, b
1, c

2, e
2, f
```

`SELECT value FROM table WHERE list_id = 1` will return three rows: (a, b, c)

Adding a new value x into list_id 2 would be something like this:

`INSERT INTO table VALUES(2, 'x')`